# Custom float style plugin to use on images for Nicedit

Tags: javascript, plugins, wysiwyg, nicedit

I have been using Nicedit and I use the following code o drag n drop images into the textarea which works fine. What i am trying to do is add a FLOAT style to the image after insertion like:

```
    <img src="blah.jpg" height="266" width="400" style="float:left">
```

I know I need to build a simple plugin but Im not too hot on javascript can anyone help? Many thanks;-)

```
 <style type="text/css">
<!--
#lft {
float: left;
width: 250px;
height: 500px;
overflow: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
#rgt {
float: right;
width: 700px;
}
#main {
width: 960px;
height: 500px;
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
}
.pc{clear:both}
-->
</style>




<script src="nicEdit.js"></script>
<script>bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });</script>
<div id="main">

<div id="lft">
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="folder">
  <option value="s">Small</option>
  <option value="m">Medium</option>
  <option value="l">Large</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="CHANGE FOLDER" /></form>
<?php 
$folder=$_POST['folder'];
if(!$folder): 
$folder='s'; endif;
$files = glob("gal/".$folder."/*.{jpg,png,gif,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
$num = $files[$i]; 
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($num); ?>
<img src="<?=$num?>" <?=$attr?>/><br />
<?php }  ?>
</div>


<div id="rgt">
<textarea name="textarea" cols="60" rows="50"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="pc"></div></div>
```